# Upload dialog in Chrome and Firefox on Mac doesn't disable mouseout event for the page element

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload, dom-events

My task is to implement a file upload form in a popup sub-menu panel. I am using XmlHttpRequest, so it's important to keep that popup opened until I receive an event status that file loading completed/failed. `Onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events are used to show/hide the popup.
On "hide" the popup panel is detached from the DOM, and cannot be used anymore as a listener for XHR events.

When I click form's "Browse" button, a system dialog window is opened above the browser. In IE, Chrome and Firefox in Windows the system dialog disables events handling by page. Which means if you move a mouse cursor out of the dialog window on one of the page element, the page won't do anything like reacting on `mouseOver`/`mouseOut` events. Unfortunately, in case with Chrome/Firefox on Mac (Safari is OK) the page elements do react on mouse over/out. And my popup menu becomes closed (due to `mouseOut` event handler for the popup) -> XHR response is not managed properly.

Assuming having an upload form in a popup is a must, what are the possible ways of keeping that panel/form visible while system Upload File dialog window is up? Probably a Mac specific solution.

Sample code can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/xqvXG/

Comment: What version of chrome / firefox are you using?

Comment: If I am understanding your situation correctly it appears to be Mac specific as you suspect. I am using PC and can't seem to reproduce the problem.

Comment: FF - 15.0.1
--
Yes, I develop on PC and don't see any problems on that platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by freezing popup panel and covering the whole page with transparent div ('glass').

In case if user chooses file(s) and upload starts, I remove the glass and unfreeze the popup using the XHR function `readyStateChangeHandler` (or may do that in handler of `load` event).

If user clicks Cancel in system dialog window or closes it with "X" button - no events passed to the page and 'glass' remains on screen. Then any click on the 'glass' causes its removal and unfreezing (or simple hiding) the popup menu.

'Glass' is required to make a single one-click point (panel) for unfreezing the popup in case if Cancel/Close were pressed. 
I wouldn't say this is a perfect solution (sometimes required extra action), but very close to what I was looking for.